# is ROS2 Foxy still viable with Nav2?

Tags: navigation, ros2, nav2, 2d-mapping

I'm currently developing a 4 Wheel-ackerman robot that runs navigates through a cave system tunnel with a pre-loaded 2D-Map. This is a government research btw.

I need to edit a behaviour tree that's why I need the foxy version. I'm currently developing the navigation system with the ros2 humble version.

My question is, is the foxy version of nav2 still recommendeded and stable? Or is it enough to run my project/research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Foxy is EOL (end of life). Reference: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Foxy-Fitzroy.html

This means that not only does it not receive the latest features in updates, but no one is doing security patching of it. I would not recommend it.